# C# Regex Pattern to remove all in a List

Tags: c#, regex, list

I have a list of strings with many items, some of which begin with a date/time in the following format:

```
2016-05-04 18:46:05.115 Copyright (c) 2014 Microsoft Corporation
```

I am looking to loop through and remove that date/time from all items in the list that contain that format.

Currently I had this:

```
var regexDateTime = "/^(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})$/";
preperationMessages = preperationMessages
    .Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, regexDateTime, ""))
    .ToList();
```

It is not filtering out any of the date at all. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is `2016-05-04 18:46:05.115` always in the beginning of your string?

Comment: When you write a regex, try putting a @ at the beginning of it.  That way you won't have to escape everything for c#  I.E. var regexDateTime = `!"/^(\d{4})..."`

Comment: and you don't need the `/` at the beginning and end of your regex

Comment: Your `$` is asserting position at end of string, but your string ends with "Corporation", not with 2 digits. Can test here: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
var regex = @"^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{3})";
```

The problem with your Regex is the '$' at the end, it means end of string and is not what you want. Other thing is, you don't use the slashes at begin and end of regex in csharp, like you do in javascript.

Comment: You still have a / at the beginning which should be removed.

Comment: Thanks, my bad. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks! also had to add .(\\d{3}) to get rid of the ms.

Answer (score 0):

This also works if you don't want to use RegEx (this may be faster too depending on the size of your messages collection:

```
int dateChars = 23;
DateTime output;

// Remove leading date(s)
preparationMessages = preparationMessages
    .Select(x => x.Length > dateChars && DateTime.TryParse(x.Substring(0, dateChars), out output) ? x.Substring(dateChars+1) : x)
    .ToList();
```